# Why using getInitialProps inside _document.js cause the Next.js application to crash?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Why not recommended to use `getInitialProps` inside `_document.js` for the static render? Why it can be destroyed the whole static rendering?

For example, I have a few cases:

1. Small e-commerce website with static pages and some dynamic pages
2. Social network with logic restrictions but on the same time I want to share some data to search engines about the profiles and posts we have in the social network (content is updating on LIVE base).

For the e-commerce I need to build the project and use `getStaticProps`?

For the social network I need to use SSR and `getServerSideProps`?

Answer (score 6):

From nextjs [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)

> A custom Document can also include `getInitialProps` for expressing **asynchronous server-rendering data requirements**.

Having `getInitialProps` inside `_document.js` will not cause your application to crash, but it has some caveats

> Document's `getInitialProps` function is not called during client-side transitions, nor when a page is statically optimized

Which means if you have some data requirements that has to be satisfied by the `getInitialProps` in the `_document.js` you have to take some precautions, because the function `getInitialProps` in `_document` will not be called for a pre-rendered page also not during the client side transitions.

One other caveat is when you try to access `ctx.req` inside `getInitialProps` it will be `undefined` for pre-rendered pages.

You can run data-fetching methods i.e `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` for each page of your application based on the need for data. If the application needs client-side data-fetching, you might wanna have a look at [swr](https://swr.now.sh/) or [react-query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query)